# How to swap s-expressions with paredit?

Tags: paredit

I often need to swap s-expressions. How can I do that with paredit? I want to do things like the following:

```
(list |1 0)
(list 0 |1)
```

or:

```
(list 1 |0)
(list |0 1)
```

Comment: Emacs has a command for that by default, it's bound to `C-M-t`.

Comment: What @DoMiNeLa10 said. At least for the two simple examples you show, I see no need for paredit. Just put your cursor between two sexps and transpose them. (And use `C-M-f` or `C-M-b` to move forward/backward over sexps.) But different people use Emacs differently.

Comment: Thanks to both of you it works perfectly. Feel free to post an answer, so that I can select it. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Emacs comes with such command out of the box, `transpose-sexps`. It's bound to <kbd>C-M-t</kbd> by default.